How to get my SharePoint site with the Sites API using the Python SDK and Site.Selected permission
Context: I need some help understanding how can I manage the storage library of my SharePoint site.
Given I have the URL of my site as "https://mycompanyname.sharepoint.com/sites/mysitename"
I first want to "access" the site in order to get its id, in order later to get the drives under the site and manages the storage library.
Question: The problem I want to solve here is to get the Site in order to access its metadata and its id.
Permissions: I believe I have the Sites.Selected permission at Application level. I can try to ask for Sites.Read.All but it will take time. Is there a way with this least permission to get the job done somehow?
So far I tried, without success:
import os
import jwt
from typing import Optional, Literal
from azure.identity.aio import ClientSecretCredential
from msgraph import GraphServiceClient
from msgraph.generated.models.drive_item import DriveItem
from msgraph.generated.models.folder import Folder
from msgraph.generated.drives.item.items.item.content.content_request_builder import ContentRequestBuilder
from kiota_abstractions.base_request_configuration import RequestConfiguration
from msgraph.generated.models.o_data_errors.o_data_error import ODataError
from src.config.loader import CONFIG
import aiofiles
from src.utils.logger import get_logger

logger = get_logger(CONFIG.logging.name, CONFIG.logging.level)

class GraphClientSingleton():
    _client = None
    _credentials = None

    @classmethod
    def get_client(cls):
        if cls._client is None:
            # cls._authority = 'login.microsoftonline.com'
            cls._credentials = ClientSecretCredential(
                tenant_id = CONFIG.msgraph.tenant_id_sharepoint,
                client_id = CONFIG.msgraph.client_id_sharepoint,
                client_secret = CONFIG.msgraph.client_secret_sharepoint,
            )
            cls._scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']

            cls._client = GraphServiceClient(credentials=cls._credentials, scopes=cls._scopes)
        return cls._client

    @classmethod
    async def decode_token(cls):
        token = await cls.get_access_token()
        decoded_token = jwt.decode(token, options={"verify_signature": False})
        return decoded_token

    @classmethod
    async def get_access_token(cls):
        if cls._credentials is None:
            cls.get_client()
        
        token = await cls._credentials.get_token(*cls._scopes)
        return token.token
    
class SharePointDAO:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = GraphClientSingleton.get_client()
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    async def test_api():
        token = await GraphClientSingleton.decode_token()
        sp_dao = SharePointDAO()
        # Example 1
        from msgraph.generated.sites.sites_request_builder import SitesRequestBuilder
        from kiota_abstractions.base_request_configuration import RequestConfiguration
        # To initialize your graph_client, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-client?from=snippets&tabs=python
        query_params = SitesRequestBuilder.SitesRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters(
            select = ["siteCollection", "webUrl"],
            filter = "siteCollection/root ne null",
        )
        request_configuration = RequestConfiguration(
            query_parameters = query_params,
        )
        sites = await sp_dao.client.sites.get(request_configuration = request_configuration)
        # Example 2 (not sure how to map the "real" URL with the needed url here)
        site_request_builder = sp_dao.client.sites.with_url(
            "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mycompanyname.sharepoint.com:/mysitename"
        )
        site = await site_request_builder.get()
        # Example 3 (return empty list under "value")
        sites = await sp_dao.client.sites.get()
        # Example 4 (return 403 error "Access Denied")
        sites = await sp_dao.client.sites.get_all_sites.get()
        logger.info(sites)
    import asyncio
    asyncio.run(test_api())


Could you confirm whether your requirement is to fetch Sharepoint sites using Python SDK?

@Sridevi Yes it is, to date I get an empty list to the API that returns without an error, so I am not sure I am using the API right or the app is misconfigured. I would like to double check with your help.

Could you please check below answer and let me know if it works?

If you are using application permissions like Sites.Read.All, you can call getAllSites endpoint and filter the sites by webUrl.
from msgraph import GraphServiceClient
from msgraph.generated.sites.get_all_sites.get_all_sites_request_builder import GetAllSitesRequestBuilder
from kiota_abstractions.base_request_configuration import RequestConfiguration

graph_client = GraphServiceClient(credentials, scopes)

query_params = GetAllSitesRequestBuilder.GetAllSitesRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters(
        filter = "webUrl eq 'https://mycompanyname.sharepoint.com/sites/mysitename'",
)

request_configuration = RequestConfiguration(
query_parameters = query_params,
)

result = await graph_client.sites.get_all_sites.get(request_configuration = request_configuration)

Or use $search query parameter:
from msgraph import GraphServiceClient
from msgraph.generated.sites.sites_request_builder import SitesRequestBuilder
from kiota_abstractions.base_request_configuration import RequestConfiguration

graph_client = GraphServiceClient(credentials, scopes)

query_params = SitesRequestBuilder.SitesRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters(
        search = "\"https://mycompanyname.sharepoint.com/sites/mysitename\"",
)

request_configuration = RequestConfiguration(
query_parameters = query_params,
)

result = await graph_client.sites.get(request_configuration = request_configuration)


I believe I don't have the Sites.Real.All permission set up and I get a 403 errore from the API response ("Access Denied"). Do you know if there is a way to get the given sites or its drives with least permissions? For instance Sites.Selected


I agree with @user2250152, you can either filter the sites by webUrl or use $search query parameter to get specific SharePoint site ID.

I have one SharePoint site named TestSite with below drives in it:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteId/drives

Response:

To get this data using Python SDK via client credentials flow, make use of below sample code that fetches site Id first with $search  and list drives data.
import asyncio
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from msgraph import GraphServiceClient
from msgraph.generated.sites.sites_request_builder import SitesRequestBuilder
from kiota_abstractions.base_request_configuration import RequestConfiguration

tenant_id = "tenantId"
client_id = "appId"
client_secret = "secret"

site_url = "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite"

credential = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id=tenant_id,
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret
)

client = GraphServiceClient(credential)

async def main():
    try:
        query_params = SitesRequestBuilder.SitesRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters(
            search=f"\"{site_url}\""
        )
        request_configuration = RequestConfiguration(
            query_parameters=query_params
        )
        
        result = await client.sites.get(request_configuration=request_configuration)
        sites = result.value
        
        if sites:
            for site in sites:
                print("Site ID:", site.id)
                print("Site Name:", site.display_name)
                print("Site Web URL:", site.web_url)
                print("-" * 50)

                site_id = site.id.split(",")[1]
                print("Actual Site ID:", site_id)

                drives = await client.sites.by_site_id(site_id).drives.get()
                for drive in drives.value:
                    print("Drive ID:", drive.id)
                    print("Drive Name:", drive.name)
                    print("-" * 50)
        else:
            print("No site found with the specified URL.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fetching site or drives: {e}")

asyncio.run(main())

Response:

Make sure to grant Sites.Read.All Microsoft Graph permission of Application type in app registration before running the code:


The code is running but I believe I don't have the Sites.Real.All permission set up and I get a 403 errore from the API response ("Access Denied").
Do you know if there is a way to get the given sites or its drives with least permissions? For instance Sites.Selected

AFAIK, you cannot list sites without granting  Sites.Read.All permission of Application type. This method does not support the Sites.Selected application permission. Check this MS Document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-search?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

Yes, indeed it is reasonable not to be able to list all Sites under the tenant without the rightfull permissions. What I want to accomplish is to be able to get only my Site for which I was granted the Sites.Selected permission with roles Read, Write, Manage, FullControl e.g. all the rights only on this site. Is it reasonable to be able to get the site with this permission but I don't know how with the Python SDK. The REST API exposes a method to get the Site by its own URL but the Python SDK only with its ID metadata

For instance here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=python#example-1-get-a-site-using-the-site-id
Examples 1 query by ID are provided both with Python and REST APIs, Example 2 query by URL only by REST
